# simple SAT practice question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: SAT sample question]

I tried to solve this and I am getting 11n/6. Am I seriously doing something really wrong or is this question wrong?

Comment: You need to find the average not the sum ...

Comment: How come every problem is "simple"?

Answer (score 5):

You need to divide the sum you calculated by $3$, since you want to find the average of $n, p, q$.

$$\frac{n + \frac n2 + \frac n3}{3} = \frac{6n + 3n + 2n }{3\cdot 6}  = \frac{11n}{18}$$